# How to split a deque in two

Tags: python, deque, python-collections

I'm writing something where I am popping and appending often and thought it would be appropriate to use [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).  However, somewhere in my code I need to divide the `deque` in two.

Consider the `deque` `d`

```
from collections import deque

d = deque(range(4))
```

I'd like to split the `deque` in this way

```
d[:2]
```

But I get an error

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-29-cb523bbbf363> in <module>()
>       3 d = deque(range(4))
>       4 
> ----> 5 d[:2]
>
> TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
> ```

---

I could do

```
list(d)[:2]

[0, 1]
```

But that seems absurd to turn it back into a list just to slice it.  Am I wrong?  Or is there another way?

Comment: @heltonbiker Thank you for finding that.  That is an exact duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `itertools.islice`, you can do

```
deque(islice(d, 2))
```